# mvcgrid.net unable to use toolbar

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, mvcgrid.net

I'm working on a website with a feature that can sort users.
I'm using mvcgrid.net libs but I can't figure it out. the toolbar doesn't work.

I used most of the basic source codes from mvcgrid.net but when i press something in the search bar it doesn't work or the items per page selection.

Comment: or is there a better way to search through a list of users?

Comment: you have to show us some code, it is impossible to guess the issue.

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this / I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have specific code to take a look at, please post. Otherwise, here are a few things you can check:

(1) Be sure you've applied the mvcgrid data attributes needed.  For example, for a search field you might have these attributes:

```
<input 
    type="search"
    data-mvcgrid-apply-additional="change"
    data-mvcgrid-type="additionalQueryOption"
    data-mvcgrid-option="search"
    data-mvcgrid-name="ContactGrid">
```

(2) Be sure the value you chose for mvcgrid-option (in this example, "search") is then added when you configure the grid.  For example:

```
MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("ContactGrid", new MVCGridBuilder<ContactViewModel>(defaults)
    .WithAdditionalQueryOptionNames("Search")
...
```

(3) You then need to read the attribute (again in the grid config) in your .WithRetrieveDataMethod()

```
string search = options.GetAdditionalQueryOptionString("search");
```

I've forgotten step 2 in the past -- that's generally what has tripped me up.